# root chef-client command not updating multiple servers on ec2 instance whenever I do change in cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, chef-infra

I am running with issue with chef server. I am trying to automate the multiple ec2 instance from my main work station and when I update any recipe inside my cookbook and when I upload the cookbook I don't seen my updated content in web browser.

I am using the below command on multiple EC2 instance.

```
* * * * * root chef-client.
```

All my ec2 instance is showing in chef manage UI along with cookbook version and whenever I try to visit public IP of any ec2 instance , I am not getting content.

But if I run manually `chef-client` on each instance then I am able to see my update content but that's not what I want. I wanted to automated each instance using this command whenever I create an EC2 instance `* * * * * root chef-client`. The command is also there in each instance whenever I create but it doesn't automate whenever I made change in cookbook and upload . Also I am not getting any error while performing the automation, just in web browser public ip getting refused to connect. Any help if you provide it will be appreciated

Comment: You seem to be using a cron job to run chef-client? If so, the job might not be running as expected depending on the user for which the crontab is updated. Also I see `.`, if this is a crontab entry, then `chef-client.` is not an actual command that will run.

Comment: ingore dot for now there no dot in that path , it just typo here . What is the solution to automate if u have any idea ?